# Swing drawing a grid. Wierd result

Tags: java, swing

So i'am using graphics2d to draw a grid on a JPanel.

But when i resize the window it will end with weird results.

```
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        /*
         * Draw the background
         */
        boolean isWhite = false;
        for(int x = 0; x < getSize().width/8; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < getSize().height/8; y++){
                if(isWhite){
                    g2d.setColor(Color.white);
                    isWhite = false;
                }else{
                    g2d.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                    isWhite = true;
                }
                g2d.fillRect(8*x, 8*y, 8, 8);
            }
        }


        g2d.dispose();

    }
```

So instead of drawing 8x8 squares it will draw horizontal rectangles (getSize().width()x8).

---

Update

I'am drawing a grid that will fill an entire JPanel. So when the window is resizing the grid will expand and that works. But it will draw weird shapes(Sometimes). The grid-cell have a constant size of 8x8

[image: Normal shape]    [image: Weird shape]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use next fix:

```
boolean isWhite = false;
boolean isWhiteLastLine = isWhite;
for(int x = 0; x < getSize().height; x=x+8){
    for(int y = 0; y < getSize().width; y=y+8){
        if(y == 0){
             isWhiteLastLine = isWhite;
        }
        if(isWhite){
             g2d.setColor(Color.white);
        }else{
             g2d.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        }
        g2d.fillRect(y, x, 8, 8);
        isWhite = !isWhite;
        if(y+8 >= getSize().width){
             isWhite = !isWhiteLastLine;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change to this

```
for(int x = 0; x < 8; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < 8; y++){
```

UPDATE: if you would like wide cells when frame is increased 
use

```
int cellWidth=getSize().width/8;
int cellHeight=getSize().height/8;
```

and

```
g2d.fillRect(cellWidth*x, cellHeight*y, cellWidth, cellHeight);
```

Comment: That will only make the grid have a constant size. The bug is still there.